# How to use absolute path of an image in css using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am trying to use absolute path of my image while using it with jquery like this but somehow it is not loading any image once I see my page. Below is my code in `testing.jsp` file

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Create overlay and append to body:
    $('<div id="overlay"/>').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: $(window).height() + 'px',
        opacity:0.4, 
        background: 'lightgray url("/testweb/src/main/webapp/resources/img/page-loader.gif") no-repeat center'
    }).hide().appendTo('body');

    // Execute refresh with interval:
    setInterval(refresh, 30 * 1000);
});
</script>
```

Directory structure is like this -

```
webapp/
|-- resources/
|   +-- img/
|           page-loader.gif
+- WEB-INF/
  +-- views/
        testing.jsp
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

Comment: The structure you show above has webapp as the root folder.  If that's the case your image path should be `/resources/img/page-loader.gif`

Comment: you're using a filesystem path. That's useless for something accessing your server's resources via http - a client cannot access anything outside the document root. try `/resources/img/...` instead

Comment: @Archer: In general when you create a project. There will be a project name which is `testweb` in my case and then you put your image in img directory which is in webapp folder. So when I right click my image and I click Copy Qualified Name in my eclipse, it gives me the full path as I provided in the question.

Comment: So what is the full url in the address bar when you got to testing.jsp?

Comment: This is what I use on the browser - `http://127.0.0.1:8080/testweb/testing`

Comment: try that - (../../resources/img/page-loader.gif)

Comment: Like this `background: 'lightgray url(../../resources/img/page-loader.gif) no-repeat center'` or the url portion will be in double quote?

Comment: @MarcB: I tried that, it doesn't work that way also somehow..

Comment: well, how would you access this image directly from a browser w/o the css? `http://example.com/path/to/image.jpg` most likely, which means `/path/to/image.jpg` is what you should be embedding in the CSS.

Comment: The url path for that image is `http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/page-loader.gif`. I know I can use this but in production our firewall will block this url so I need to run it from my local folder somehow..

Comment: And also - In our company this is the way I am specifying any image in my html body by using the image tag as below. Now how would I use the same thing in my above jquery to specify the image path if local path is not working somehow?

`<res:img class="hostL" value="${res.img.local.img['logo_png.png']}" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can either use the URL of the image including domain: http://www.yourwebsite.com/webapp/resources/img/page-loader.gif 
or use relative path: 
../../resources/img/page-loader.gif

Answer (score 0):

jquery runs on the client machine.

the image is located on the server machine.

if you specify absolute path using anything that runs on the client machine, it will not work because client cannot access the server directly.

you have to put the image in the website in some 'resources' or whatever folder, and use relative path.

Comment: He's not trying to access an image on the client.  I'm not sure where you got that impression from.

Comment: archer please read my answer again before downvoting. i wrote that jquery is client side script and cannot access images on the server. i dont know where from you got the impression that i was speaking about images on the client.

Comment: Okay - sorry that was a misunderstanding on my part.  My apologies.  The downvote remains though as what you *are* saying is even more incorrect than I thought!

Comment: I think I understand where your misunderstanding comes from.  If an image url begins with a forward slash then the browser will take the path from the root of the domain you are on.  If it doesn't begin with a forward slash then it is taken as a relative address, from the folder the file is in (whether it's a css file or a web page).  He doesn't want `file://` when he says "absolute path" (but that *will* still work if the file is there.)

Comment: i see. i thought by absolute path he meant absolute as in c:/blabla/blabla which will not work.